# Есть ли аналог shared_mutex в linux kernel?

Tags: c++, linux, c, ядро

Есть ли аналог shared_mutex в linux kernel? То-есть мутекс который можно залочить только при записи в модуле ядра linux.

Comment: https://docs.kernel.org/locking/mutex-design.html где `mutex *` находиться в shared memory.

Comment: есть, `rw_semaphore` и `rwlock_t`...